# After update macOS got Addigy

Tags: macos, macbook

How to remove Addigy and why it installed on my MacBook? I tried to google it, but havent got anything. Also I enmailed their support, but didnt got any info about my problem

Comment: Update of what? In any case, this seems like legitimate software.

Comment: Addigy is normally found on corporate computers, enabling IT to remotely manage them. if yours is a corporate Mac, then speak to your IT department. Removing MDM software is generally not possible without the co-operation of the managing organisation.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I think you can put it as an answer here, It clarifies correctly the situation, explains what the questioned application is and its purposes. Also informs who to contact, which is the managing organisation and not Apple.

Comment: @Prado - sure, I can throw it in as an answer. It doesn't look like the OP has been back since their post, though, so I'm guessing that might be the end of the line for it ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Addigy](https://www.addigy.com) is normally found on corporate computers, enabling IT to remotely manage them.
If yours is a corporate Mac, then speak to your IT department.

Removing MDM [mobile device management] software is generally not possible without the co-operation of the managing organisation.